# With lombok, can required-arg constructor coexist with @Value, @Builder and @Builder.Default annotations?

Tags: java, lombok

Using lombok (1.18.24), is it possible to generate (1) a constructor that accepts args only for non-initialized members **and also** (2) a builder? I've tried a variety of annotation sets:

1. []

```java
@Value @Builder class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    Foo(String alpha) {this.alpha = alpha;}
    static void bar() {new Foo("y");}
}
```

```
[ERROR] Foo.java:[6,8] constructor Foo in class Foo cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.lang.String
[ERROR]   found:    java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

2. [AllArgsConstructor]

```java
@Value @Builder @AllArgsConstructor class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    Foo(String alpha) {this.alpha = alpha;}
    static void bar() {new Foo("y");}
}
```

```
[ERROR] Foo.java:[11,47] variable bravo might not have been initialized
```

3. [RequiredArgsConstructor]

```java
@Value @Builder @RequiredArgsConstructor class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    static void bar() {new Foo("y");}
}
```

```
[ERROR] Foo.java:[10,29] constructor Foo in class Foo cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR]   found:    java.lang.String
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

4. [AllArgsConstructor, RequiredArgsConstructor]

```java
@Value @Builder @AllArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    static void bar() {new Foo("y");}
}
```

```
[ERROR] constructor Foo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) is already defined in class Foo
[ERROR] Foo.java:[8,37] constructor Foo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) is already defined in class Foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Lombok makes an all-args constructor for you **unless** you write a constructor yourself, in that case, you have to add `@AllArgsConstructor`. Which you should do here. You may make it private if you like (`@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`. It needs to exist for lombok's builder to make an object. It needs to include the defaulted stuff (that's just a default, so, the builder needs to be capable of passing a non-default value, too).
2. The problem is in your own code - you wrote your own constructor which doesn't set the `bravo` field. In general it's a bad idea to also have your own constructor, especially if said constructor *does not* call the lombok-generated one. The `@Builder.Default` modifies what builder does (namely: It will use that `"X"` value if you ask a builder to `build()` when no value for `bravo` has ever been set for it). It removes that `"X"` as it goes, and `@Value` has made that field `final` of course - so, your constructor fails to set an uninitialized (because builder 'takes away' the `"X"`) `final` field, which is a compiler error.
3. Same problem.
4. AllArgs and RequiredArgs are the same constructor, so lombok tries to generate them both, which doesn't work.

```
@Value @Builder @AllArgsConstructor class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    Foo(String alpha) {this(alpha, "x");}
    static void bar() {new Foo("y");}
}
```

Is what you're looking for. Or, more likely, *get rid* of that constructor, and write:

```
@Value @Builder @AllArgsConstructor class Foo {
    String alpha;
    @Builder.Default String bravo = "x";
    static void bar() {return builder().alpha("y").build(); }
}
```

It's generally not a good idea to hybridize anything in programming - and you're hybridizing your approach to construction here. Some custom constructor for some, builders for others. If you must, okay, but, it's a cost. One of the costs is confusion (that seems to have happened here). Another is bug-prone code: bugs that cannot be easily found (because one person *always* uses one way and therefore a bug in the other way isn't in any of their code paths, but it is in yours). A third is style debates; if there are 2 ways to do the same thing, either code arbitrarily picks a way (that's bad; causes code to be needlessly difficult to read by doing the same thing in different ways, which incorrectly insinuates there is a meaningful difference the reader will either be worrying about, or will be spending some time on to chase down that, no, in fact, it doesn't matter - or, you need a style guide to dictate when to use which way. And then you need to enforce that style guide which is very hard to do; most folks don't, as a rule, want to spend time writing a custom lint rule).

NB: I said 'generally not a good idea' - not 'it is always wrong'. There are good reasons to hybridize but be aware that **it is a cost** to introduce it. Hence, the onus of making an argument is on the author of the hybridized approach. They need to explain that despite the significant costs introduced by having multiple ways to do the same thing, that it's nevertheless worthwhile here. Your code is clearly a simplified example for the sake of asking a streamlined SO question (excellent!), so perhaps there *is* a good reason here. However, in the likely scenario that there is not - get rid of that hand-written constructor.

Comment: This inner class exists within 'Test' class so I'm OK with tech debt. I'm just looking for maximum concision. I want to be able to call both `new Foo("y")` and `foo.toBuilder().alpha("y").build()` (the real code has more params). Confusion here is around whether a default value "x" affects @Builder, @RequiredArgsConstructor and/or handwritten constructors. Lombok can't make up its mind and is not in agreement with IntelliJ IDEA's 'Structure' pane. Your proposed solutions work but are more verbose. Not a huge deal but I wonder if it's possible to do this with annotations alone.

Comment: Lombok can make up its mind perfectly well (SOURCE: I wrote most of that code). It's possible the intellij plugin (which is externally maintained) doesn't get this right, in which case, file a bug (with the plugin, not lombok itself). As the `@Builder.Default` naming suggests, it affects __the builder__. only.

Comment: Whoa, thanks for your work on lombok. Great tool. I'd argue that `@Builder.Default` annotation should affect neither `@RequiredArgsConstructor` nor handwritten constructors. Documentation for the former states that "all non-initialized final fields get a parameter." It's confusing that `@Builder.Default` invalidates what appears to be an inline initialization. This design decision only comes into play if users mix builders and standard constructors so maybe lombok devs treat it as an irrelevant use case. Anyways, I understand how it works now. Thx again.

Comment: It doesn't affect constructors. It is indeed confusing that it removes inline initialization; the problem is, imagine the expression has side effects, e.g. `foo++` where `foo` is a static field. Leaving the initial value intact means creating 1 obj via builder now increments __two times__.

Comment: Ah, good point about side effects. I guess status quo is the least bad option. I think confusion is magnified by erroneous IDE plugin behavior. I created [bug](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1164) for that.